# Slack API - how to send ephemeral message on im message event (channel ID is not a valid channel)?

Tags: slack, slack-api

I have an App that subscribes to the [messages.im](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im) event, and when triggered by a direct message between two users, I get the following json sent to my callback URI (every identifier was edited to make it anonymous):

```
{
    "token": "K5ROtL7xMS1Fv8zo8V33IAx8",
    "team_id": "T32SZGR2P",
    "api_app_id": "AP50R2741",
    "event": {
        "client_msg_id": "ca24d63d-c022-4629-a618-9d9a2ee0097c",
        "type": "message",
        "text": "test message\n<@ULAJP1B25>",
        "user": "U232XAB7X",
        "ts": "1592504332.001900",
        "team": "T32SZGR2P",
        "blocks": [
            {
                "type": "rich_text",
                "block_id": "T2Fe6",
                "elements": [
                    {
                        "type": "rich_text_section",
                        "elements": [
                            {
                                "type": "text",
                                "text": "test message\n"
                            },
                            {
                                "type": "user",
                                "user_id": "ULAJP1B25"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ],
        "channel": "DLAJ2HDNU",
        "event_ts": "1592504332.001900",
        "channel_type": "im"
    },
    "type": "event_callback",
    "event_id": "Ev211G7DRFK7",
    "event_time": 1592504332,
    "authed_users": [
        "U232XAB7X"
    ]
}
```

I have two issues here:

1. I can't seem to send [ephemeral messages](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postEphemeral) to this thread as the
   given `channel` (`DLAJ2HDNU`) is invalid and it gives `channel_not_found`. I tried gathering more information about the conversation through [conversations.info](https://api.slack.com/methods/conversations.info) but it also
   gives `channel_not_found`;
2. I cannot identify what's the recipient's user ID or username, as I only have one `user` property, that defines who sent the message.

So my questions is: how may I achieve 1 and or 2?

---

Also, for context, my objective is to listen for `@mentions` and direct messages in order to check if the mentioned user/recipient is afk and send a message to whoever mentioned them saying they may take a while to answer.

Comment: In the end, it should be a conversation between User A, User B and the bot, right? Can't you get some more information by `conversation.members`?

Comment: I finally reached to Slack's support last week (somehow forgot about it before asking here on SO). Their answer is that `"channel": "DLAJ2HDNU"` is a valid channel, but the token I had doesn't have permission to post there or retrieve more information about it. And yes, I had tried using `conversation.members`, but due to the token permission, also got some variation of "not found". So in the end, all I need is to get the user's token.